# How to render HTML when inside {{}} on Brade with ternary operator in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, ternary-operator

I have the follow code in Blade using a ternary operator:

```
<td>{{isset($arrTemp[$ccc->id]) ? "<a hfet='".url('/cc/'.$cc->id)."'>".count($arrTemp[$cc->id])."</a>": 'N/A'}}</td>
```

If it find somenthing for the array key `$cc->id`, should thisplay the value with the link atteched to it.

But the page is rendering `<a hfet='http://my.test/cc/56526235'>4</a>` the string itself.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `{{ }}` the output is automatically escaped to prevent XSS attacks. You can use `{!! !!}` instead, which will not escape the string.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data